# Angular not adding /

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a angular project that behaves fine on my localhost, but when the site is deployed to the live URL, angular is not adding a / before #.

So what i get is:
somesite.com/something#/myview

What i want is:
somesite.com/something/#/myview

I'm not sure what causes this - maybe my route?

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/questions.html',
            controller: 'QuestionController'
        })
    .when('/familie', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/familie.html'
        })
    .when('/single', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/single.html'
        })
    .when('/complete', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/complete.html'
        })
    .when('/vinder', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/vinder.html',
            controller: 'WinnerController'
        })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
```

Comment: Just init your angular application at `somesite.com/something/`

Comment: put `/` before your template path..most of missed that

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior. AngularJS uses tags (the '#') to prevent that the browsers actually navigates. This is because AngularJS are always single page applications. You only have control over the part that is after the '#', and not the part before it.

Answer (score 0):

use     href="#/single"

instead of href="/single" where you are invoking the path in your html file.
also use init as

```
app.run( function ( apiService ) {
    apiService.init( '' );
} );
```